# Wifi adapter randomly drops

Tags: wireless, usb

I'm currently using this: https://www.tendacn.com/us/product/U6.html

I haven't install any of its drivers, I just plug it in and it works. But, my problem is it drops randomly that I have to unplug and plug it again in order for it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I'm currently on Ubuntu MATE 18.04

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have services running that are getting in the way. On my system, for example, I knocked out network-manager, and networking services.

First, open a terminal window and see what's running:

```
service --status-all
```

If the services display with a + they are running. To stop them:

```
service network-manager stop
service networking stop
```

See if that is any better for a few sessions. (You might find you need to restart the service.)
If that is the answer, look up how to stop the services from running in the first place (I don't know your specific system).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/kucaxey which one? and how do i resume it again?

Comment: See which one(s) you have and try them in turn, or together.

To start a service, for example:

    `service networking start`

Comment: Tried stopping networking, didn't work still drops.